# Return dictionary key if one of key's values is within string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

So I have a dictionary with various keys, and these keys have values in lists of various sizes:

```
dict = {'a' : ['one', 'two'],
        'b' : ['three', 'four', 'five'],
        'c' : ['six']}
```

If I have a string as follows:

```
stringa = 'blahfourblah'
```

I want to return 'b', since one of the values of key 'b' (i.e. 'four') is found within stringa.

I have tried the following code:

```
[k for k, v in dict.items() if stringa in v]
```

But this only returns the following:

```
[]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you think `'blahfourblah' in ['three', 'four', 'five']` can work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition `stringa in v` is not correct, since it will check if the entire `stringa` is an element in the list. The element `'blahfourblah'` is not in the list `['three', 'four', 'five']`. So that cannot work.

You can use a construct with `any(..)`:

```
[k for k, vs in d.items() if any(v in stringa for v in vs)]
```

Here for every key-value pair we will check the condition `any(v in stringa for v in vs)`. This means that we iterate over every element in `v`, and check if that element `v` is a substring of `stringa`. If there is such element, `any(..)` will return `True`. Otherwise it will return `False`. The moment it has found such an element, it will stop searching for another one.

Generating:

```
>>> [k for k, vs in d.items() if any(v in stringa for v in vs)]
['b']
```

> **Note:** do not use `dict` as a variable name: it will overwrite the `dict` class reference. I used `d` here.

Comment: Just a minor note, I think it should be `v in stringa`.

Comment: Damn my slow mobile fingers!